# Spring integration TCP Server multiple connections of more than 5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tcp, spring-integration, serversocket

I'm using the following version of Spring Boot and Spring integration now.

```
spring.boot.version 2.3.4.RELEASE
spring-integration  5.3.2.RELEASE
```

My requirement is to create a TCP client server communication and i'm using spring integration for the same. The spike works fine for a single communication between client and server and also works fine for exactly 5 concurrent client connections.

The moment i have increased the concurrent client connections from 5 to any arbitary numbers, it doesn't work but the TCP server accepts only 5 connections.

I have used the 'ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory' mentioned by **@Gary Russell** in one of the earlier comments ( for similar requirements ) but still doesn't work.

Below is the code i have at the moment.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class SocketConfig {

    @Value("${socket.host}")
    private String clientSocketHost;

    @Value("${socket.port}")
    private Integer clientSocketPort;

    @Bean
    public TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutGate(AbstractClientConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        TcpOutboundGateway gate = new TcpOutboundGateway();
        //connectionFactory.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
        gate.setConnectionFactory(clientCF());
        return gate;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpInboundGateway tcpInGate(AbstractServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory)  {
        TcpInboundGateway inGate = new TcpInboundGateway();
        inGate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        inGate.setRequestChannel(fromTcp());
        return inGate;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel fromTcp() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    // Outgoing requests
    @Bean
    public ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory clientCF() {
        TcpNetClientConnectionFactory tcpNetClientConnectionFactory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(clientSocketHost, serverCF().getPort());
        tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setSingleUse(true);
        ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory threadAffinityClientConnectionFactory = new ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory(
            tcpNetClientConnectionFactory);
        // Tested with the below too.
        // threadAffinityClientConnectionFactory.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
        return threadAffinityClientConnectionFactory;
    }


    // Incoming requests
    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory serverCF() {
        log.info("Server Connection Factory");
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory tcpNetServerConnectionFactory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(clientSocketPort);
        tcpNetServerConnectionFactory.setSerializer(new CustomSerializer());
        tcpNetServerConnectionFactory.setDeserializer(new CustomDeserializer());
        tcpNetServerConnectionFactory.setSingleUse(true);
        return tcpNetServerConnectionFactory;
    }


    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor () {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(50);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
        executor.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
        executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(120);
        return executor;
    }

}
```

Did anyone had the same issue with having multiple concurrent Tcp client connections of more than 5 ?

Thanks

### Client Code:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ScheduledTaskService {

    // Timeout in milliseconds
    private static final int SOCKET_TIME_OUT = 18000;
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 32000;
    private static final int ETX = 0x03;
    private static final String HEADER = "ABCDEF             ";
    private static final String data = "FIXED DARATA"
    private final AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();

    @Async
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 100000)
    public void sendDataMessage() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int numberOfRequests = 10;

        Callable<String> executeMultipleSuccessfulRequestTask = () -> socketSendNReceive();

        final Collection<Callable<String>> callables = new ArrayList<>();
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, numberOfRequests).forEach(i-> {
            callables.add(executeMultipleSuccessfulRequestTask);
        });
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfRequests);

        List<Future<String>> taskFutureList = executorService.invokeAll(callables);
        List<String> strings = taskFutureList.stream().map(future -> {
            try {
                return future.get(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "";
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        strings.forEach(string -> log.info("Message received from the server: {} ", string));

    }

    public String socketSendNReceive() throws IOException{
        int requestCounter = atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();

        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 8000;

        Socket socket = new Socket();
        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
        socket.connect(address, SOCKET_TIME_OUT);
        socket.setSoTimeout(SOCKET_TIME_OUT);

        //Send the message to the server
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);

        bos.write(HEADER.getBytes());
        bos.write(data.getBytes());
        bos.write(ETX);
        bos.flush();
//        log.info("Message sent to the server : {} ",  envio);

        //Get the return message from the server
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        String response =  receber(is);
        log.info("Received response");
        return response;
    }

    private String receber(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        final StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        int readLength;
        byte[] buffer;
        buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        do {
            if(Objects.nonNull(in)) {
                log.info("Input Stream not null");
            }
            readLength = in.read(buffer);
            log.info("readLength : {}  ", readLength);
            if(readLength > 0){
                stringBuffer.append(new String(buffer),0,readLength);
                log.info("String ******");
            }
        } while (buffer[readLength-1] != ETX);
        buffer = null;
        stringBuffer.deleteCharAt(resposta.length()-1);
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in the framework that would limit the connections to 5; if you can provide a small, complete, example that exhibits this behavior, I can take a look to see what's wrong.

Comment: Hi Gary, Thanks for the quick response. I have added the client code to the question now which will push 10 concurrent messages onto the server socket. When the client code tries to push 10 messages concurrently, then only 5 messages are being accepted from the server socket and will get only 5 responses.

Comment: The same client code is tested against another standard java server socket ( doesn't use spring integration ) but works fine for 10 concurrent client connection requests . Ref link https://www.baeldung.com/a-guide-to-java-sockets

Comment: I see that you not closing the socket, but that shouldn't matter. I see no reason why you would be limited to 5 connections. Again, I need a complete example project posted someplace, so I can see what's going on.

Comment: That requires some proprietary jars - can you strip it down to the bare minimum, and with NO Lombok?

Comment: Removed unrelated dependencies and pushed the code to the repository.

Comment: It still requires DB2 - please reduce it to the absolute minimum that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: @GaryRussell  I have removed some more unrelated dependencies now and pushed the code.

Comment: This does not run `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest`, due to some swagger stuff - can you not just strip it down all the way to just the TCP server config? e.g. extract that part to a new project?

Comment: I have now removed all the unrelated dependencies and just had the socket config in place. Code pushed now to the repo.

Comment: I figured it out; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are opening the connections all at the same time, you need to increase the `backlog` property on the server connection factory.

It defaults to 5.

```java
/**
 * The number of sockets in the connection backlog. Default 5;
 * increase if you expect high connection rates.
 * @param backlog The backlog to set.
 */
public void setBacklog(int backlog) {
```

Comment: Wow. works like a charm. You have mentioned earlier that the current code is not closing the connections.  Where should we close the connections ? I assume that as i'm setting         tcpNetServerConnectionFactory.setSingleUse(true);  and also tcpNetClientConnectionFactory.setSingleUse(true); the connections will be automatically closed.   If the understanding is wrong, then at what point the connections should be closed.

Comment: Thanks so much for the same. Much appreciated for the response !!!

Comment: Yes, setting `singleUse=true` will cause the server to close the socket after it sends the reply. But I think it would be cleaner to do it on the client side after you receive the reply. It seems wrong to "rely" on the server doing it for you. You're not using the client connection factory in that client, you are creating a `Socket` yourself.

Comment: A note below:   When i'm running the process check on the socket port ( 8000 ) , can see lot of "CLOSE_WAIT"  states.  So looks like the server socket is not closing those connections after sending back the response ?  The client code which is shared earlier cant be changed as its being used by an external client and so its our responsibility to close off the connections once successful response has been sent to the client.

Comment: Yes; if the client doesn't close the socket, it will stay in CLOSE_WAIT; it is not correct for the application not to close it. Google CLOSE_WAIT.